# how to specify the libraries to Xcode linker and preprocessor directive to Xcode compiler?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I want to set up CPLEX(an optimization library) in Xcode IDE（mac os）,some configurations have to be done, But I don't know how to do following two installing indications(I want to know how to do it in Xcode IDE build settings, not in terminal of command line). who can help me, thanks:

1.Compiler options: Give your compiler a preprocessor directive by means of the option -D, like this:

-DIL_STD

2.Linker options: Specify the libraries to your linker, like this:

-lilocplex -lconcert

Here is the correct order of the builds of the libraries:

-lilocplex -lconcert -lcplex -lm -lpthread

Comment: Xcode is not a compiler.

Comment: Now Hello world can be run in it by C++ programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the project and go to build settings in the project editor. There are settings there for passing options to the compiler and linker.

Comment: i searched all items over the build settings, and i can't find out the right items. can you indicate them to me? thanks.

Comment: You can put `-DIL_STD` in the 'Other C flags`. You could put `-lilocplex -lconcert -lcplex` in 'other linker flags', or you could add those libraries to the target (build phases, add libraries to the 'link binary with library' area). You will not need the `-lm` or `-lpthread` flags.

Comment: thanks for your valuable help. both link and build are successful following your indications.

Answer (score 0):

just do as bames53 wrote.In fact I meet another problem after those two steps mentioned above, because I assign a 32 bit library directories in library searching path. To avoid it, one should change library path to 64 bit. If you want to use 32bit lib, then change the architectures from "64-bit intel" to "32-bit intel" in the build settings.In fact, mac os is usually 64bit.